Why is incest morally wrong?
I understand that incest isnt right but i cant figure out why. Excluding pedophilia and grooming like relationships between a parent and child, why is it actually wrong? If two adult cousins or siblings form a relationship without the intention of having children what are they doing wrong? Ive usually thought of morality as how you affect the people around you. I mean if its negatively affecting the people in your life then it probably isnt very good. But a brother and sister dating doesnt do any harm to anyone. I do think incest is very gross and i am actually against it but im not sure why? I am asking from more of a philosophical standpoint than a biological one. Excluding procreation which is a very good argument against any form of incest, i am asking about incest that would have no negative effect on the people around you or any actual consequences. If two adult siblings are in a consensual relationship who does it actually harm and why would it be wrong? (at least in the context of our current western society)

Welcome to PhilSE! Don't take closure personally. Please review the FAQ for more information.

Culturally, incest being immoral isn't universal. There are many cultures who regularly participate in it.

"Brave New World": when familial love is usurped by sexual appetite, everything is sexualized through depersonalization.

@Cdn_Dev although I heard of many agrarian cultures who value marriage between first cousins (because it prevents scattering land properties) i never heard of any culture where brother/sister relationships are considered acceptable. Do you have examples?

@Hokon Is that happening now? I'm a bit unsure. Can you help me im confused?

@8Mad0Manc8 Not in society overall, but in cases where incest appears it seems to mess up a person's sexuality in the way I described. Of course one can always ask: "ok so adult sibling incest is unwise, but is it immoral"? Answering that would be much more involved.

That's a touchy but interesting topic. I'll start with the observation that some level of prohibition of incest (within siblings or between parents and their children) is quasi universal in human societies, today and yesterday, though not necessarily formalized in law.
"Quasi" because there are a few exceptions, like the frequent marriages between a pharaoh and his sister way back when.
At a different level, between 1st degree cousins, marriage or intercourse is generally not prohibited, although it is frown upon in some cultures.
There are very few universals in human cultures. So this one calls for an explanation, I think.
First, let's see what biology has to say. Biology is universal in a way that culture cannot be, because we're one species but with different cultures. We all know that the offsprings of an incestuous couple have statistically a greater chance of suffering from genetic diseases. Cosanguinity ("same blood") is the classic name for this problem, and it has been the classic answer to your question: Incest is prohibited in all societies under the sun because it may lead to weak and sick offspring. All societies since time immemorial have observed this correlation between cosanguinity and diseases, which is why they all disapprove of it. We could call this the "classic answer". It's a starting point.
A tempting variant of the biological answer would be to say that incest prohibition provided a clear-enough Darwinian advantage that it wrote itself in our genome somehow, among the many instinctual pleasures (sugar, sex...) and aversions (snakes, large insects and spiders) carried by the human species. This is in my view not a good position, nor is it frequently held.
Since the advent of sociology and ethnology and all that jazz, another and IMO quite interesting answer has been proposed, I think first by Levi-Straus but don't take my word for it. The idea is that human societies are based on exchange, on trade. If nobody talked to anybody else, if nobody traded with anybody else, there would be no society. Exchange is what defines a human society. And in many "primitive" (traditional, non modernist) societies, nothing is more valuable, as a tradable good, than women. I know how awful it sounds but in Afghanistan for instance, a bride is worth traditionally about a hundred cows. Fathers exchange their daughters for the equivalent of about $100,000, to be paid by the boy's father. The price fluctuates widely, depending on the bride and many other factors.
In those traditional systems, marriage is NOT a matter of love, or very rarely so, but a matter of money, and most importantly a matter of political alliances between tribes.
In this context, incest prohibition makes society, it creates social bounds between different families and is therefore a sine qua non condition for society to exist at all.
Naturally, this sociological answer is often expressed in sociological terms such as endogamy prohibition, or mandatory exogamy.
Exogamy rules are universal, in this explanation, to prevent us from going back to a pre-social, more animal state in our development, when our ancestors were copulating freely within families like other mammals do. Without somw degree of incest prohibition, no true society can prosper and thrive, beyond the nuclear family level. (Pre-)historically, (pre-)humans evolved from having majoritarilly no problem with incest, to a near-universal taboo on it nowadays. This happened because the only societies that managed to develop - to emerge - were making it taboo.

Your answer is factually wrong with regards to near-universal ban. You should check the pretty thorough and weighed accepted answer of the linked question.

@PhilipKlöcking This link "to policy around the world varies wildly. ... Besides legal prohibitions, at least some forms of incest are also socially taboo or frowned upon in most cultures around the world." So my answer is NOT factually wrong after all.

A ban is not the same as a social/cultural taboo, it involves a legal connotation IMHO. Since incestuous acts between adults are explicitly not legally prohibited for one third of humankind (many first world) plus many other countries not having legal provisions at all (that is "hard facts"), it would be weird to say "without incest prohibition, no true society can prosper and thrive". Also, "some form of incest" is far from an almost universal ban you suggest.

@PhilipKlöcking Okay so the word "ban" is too strong, "taboo" is better. Fair enough, I'll edit accordingly.

Thank you! I edited my question to be a little more specific to what i was thinking but your answer actually helped me a lot. I genuinely really appreciate your insight and it was seriously very helpful!!

@sofi Most welcome. Happy to be of help. :-)

Aren't we all commiting incest if the current population are descendants of a mitochondrial eve?
